# WPF How do I return value to the main program from Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am new to WPF and C# and cannot understand how to return a value from inside a `Button_Click`.

I am trying to get the user to select a file location then pass that location to the main program. Here is my code so far which works but I cannot pass the string back.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }   

    public static string Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        string FolderLocation  = dialog.SelectedPath; //this is c:/folder

        return FolderLocation;
    }

    // need to use FolderLocation here to do some stuff.
}
```

Comment: Add global variable and here u go(?)

Comment: To where do you want to return the folder location?

Comment: do you want to use it inside the same class? if that's so, then you need go as @Sebastian506563 suggests. Just add a private string folderLocation variable and assign the value to it

Comment: Typically, you'd do one of two things with the selected file path: pass it to some method that will actually _do_ something with the file; or just display it on the screen. If the former, then you should do that in your `Click` event handler (possibly with appropriate logic to ensure the UI thread is not blocked while processing the file). If the latter, then you should assign the value to the property (preferably in a view model) that represents the file name in the display. Without a [mcve] to show exactly what you're doing, it's not possible to provide a good, _specific_ answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question shouldn't even compile. The signature of the Button_Click event cannot have a return value.

While it's also an option to store this selection in a "global" variable, this doesn't solve the dilemma of what to do with the selection once it's stored there. Unless the state of the selection needs to be maintained, the better solution is to immediately pass it to a method that will consume the information.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            ProcessFolderLocation(dialog.SelectedPath);
        }

        private void ProcessFolderLocation(string location)
        {
            // ... Do something with your selected folder location
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you very much for your time and for dealing with my very simple question , like I said I am very new. Learning all the syntax is one thing thinking in a logical manner well lets just say I have much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

So as I read you are new at C# so you need to read about global variables. For now I will help you with this simple sample:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string globalVariable; //this is global variable (easiest one)

    public static string Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        string FolderLocation  = dialog.SelectedPath; //this is c:/folder


        globalVariable=FolderLocation;

    }
    public void MethodX()
    {
     string variableWithValueFromButtonClick=globalVariable;
    //U can use your globalVariable here or wherever u want inside class MainWindow

    }
```

And [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable) you have some tutorial